# How to do a class switch / dynamic class / return

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hard to describe my problem in the title.
I use Unity 2017.2 with C#. This not direct a Unity question, more a C# based Unity.

I have an abstract class DatabaseTemplate.cs, that has some methods.
Now i have two classes that derive from that template:

BaseMysql.cs and BaseSQlite.cs.
All works, both classes has the same methods with same parameters and return types. But both using different libraries.

Now i try to implement a dynamic class or function, that check:

Using Sqlite or Mysql, using that class to use that methods. One central class to do something like:

object userCount = DatabaseManager.QueryScalar("SELECT count(*) FROM users");

QueryScalar is the method by BaseSQlite/BaseMysql. I don't have a clue. Anyone can describe how to archive this? Thank you.

Comment: Unclear. `QueryScalar` is a virtual method in `DatabaseTemplate`?

Comment: Did you try to implement QueryScalar method in abstract class?

Comment: QueryScalar is the method in BaseSQlite/BaseMysql, and also describes in the Abstract class DatabaseTemplate. I just want to switch from what class i will execute the method.

Comment: You'll probably _not_ want to have that SQL statement there. It may have to be different for different SQL dialects.

Comment: "Ist just want to switch from what class i will execute the method." I don't get that. If `DatabaseManager` is created to be `DatabaseTemplate DatabaseManager = new BaseMysql()` then BaseMysql's implementation will be called ... and accordingly for BaseSqlite

Comment: @Fildor thanks for the tipp, i know that. There will be a another class to build the query for the chosen database.